# Problems opening a java file using gedit on terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal, gedit

I'm using the terminal to test all my Java code. I have a Mac. When I compile for example:

->javac MyJava.java (it compiles perfectly)

->java MyJava (it works perfectly)

But the problem is when I'm trying to edit that java file using gedit, like this:

->gedit *.java

it displays an error:

->(gedit:12827): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

What would be the cause? Also I already have installed gedit on my Mac, but still it is giving the same problem.

Regards!

Comment: It is the problem of your display, you need to check the XWindow setting. Try to use it with pure terminal editor such as Vi or nano or Emacs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to launch an editor (gedit) that requires Xwindows. Download and install a Xserver (like [XQuartz](http://www.xquartz.org/)) or use a terminal based editor like vim, or use a native Mac editor.